# Regex perl with letters and numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract a strings from a text file that contains both letters and numbers. The lines start like this

```
Report filename: ABCL00-67900010079415.rpt ______________________
```

All I need is the last 8 numbers so in this example that would be 10079415

```
while(<DATA>){
if (/Report filename/) {
  my ($bagID) = ( m/(\d{8}+)./ );
  print $bagID;
}
```

Right now this prints out the first 8 but I want the last 8.

Comment: Is the length of the numeric part of the file name constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to escape the dot, so that it would match the 8 digit characters which exists before the dot charcater.

```
my ($bagID) = ( m/(\d{8}+)\./ );
```

`.` is  a special character in regex which matches any character. In-order to match a literal dot, you must need to escape that.

Comment: be greedy `my ($bagID) = ( m/.*(\d{8}+)/ );`

Comment: Matches highlighted portion of this string 'ABCL`10079415.`00-67900010079415.rpt some stu10079415.'

Answer (score 0):

To match the *last* of anything, just precede it with a wildcard that will match as many characters as possible

```
my ($bag_id) = / .* (\d{8}) /x
```

Note that I have also use the `/x` modifier so that the regex can contain insignificant whitespace for readability. Also, your `\d{8}+` is what is called a *possessive quantifier*; it is used for optimising some regex constructions and makes no difference at the end of the pattern